# How select mysql with condition on nested array json?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

i'm create a table have one json column and data of inserted has below structure:

```
{
   "options" : {
      "info" :  [
                 {"data" : "data1", "verified" : 0},
                 {"data" : "data2", "verified" : 1},
                 ... and more
                ],
     "otherkeys" : "some data..."
   }
}
```

i want to run a query to get `data` of `verified = 1` "info"

this is for mysql 5.7 comunity running on windows 10

```
    select id, (meta->"$.options.info[*].data") AS `data`
    from tbl
    WHERE meta->"$.options.info[*].verified" = 1
```

is expect the output of "data2" but the actual output is nothing.

below query worked perfectly

```
    select id, (meta->"$.options.info[*].data") AS `data`
    from tbl
    WHERE meta->"$.options.info[1].verified" = 1
```

but i need to search all item in array not only index `1`

how can fix it ?

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT `id`, (`meta` -> '$.options.info[*].data') `data`
FROM `tbl`
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`meta` -> '$.options.info[*].verified', '1');
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=faaeec22c0e49445940db0162f5206ab).

Comment: almost solved my problem.
but how can retrieve only ```data``` have ```verified = 1``` ??

your query return all data if have at least one ```verified = 1```.
 At your link too ```data1``` and ```data2``` has returned.